# Python - <urllib.request.Request object at 0x0000000002E8FF60>

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I do this:

```
url = 'http://www.example.com'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8') # data should be bytes
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
print(req)
```

Using Python, I get this:

```
< urllib.request.Request object at 0x0000000002E8FF60 >
```

What does it mean?

What happened to my `req` variable?

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is an object of type `Request` A request object is an abstraction of a URL request.

To view the elements, you can do `req.__dict__`

Also, `dir(req)` would give you the available keys in the request object.

Here is the documentation of the [Request class](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request)

The reason you are seeing `<urllib.request.Request object at 0x0000000002E8FF60>` is, by default it provides the object in the following format:

(Normally, you would override this by specifying `__unicode__`, which would refer to some property within the class object)